# In c++, is it possible for a class to have an array that contains objects of another class?

Tags: c++, oop, object

For example, I have a class called Apple and another class called Basket and I want the class Basket to have a private attribute that is an array of Apple objects.

My code:

basket.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <apple.h>

// defin basket
class Basket {
    //class attrs; private
    private:
        std::string name;
        // I want Basket objects to have an array of Apple objects
        // How do I do this?
        Apple [];
    public: //class function
        Basket(std::string); //constructor
        std::string get_name() {return (name);}
};
```

apple.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// defin apple
class Apple {
    //class attrs; private
    private:
        std::string name;
    public: //class function
        Apple(std::string); //constructor
        std::string get_name() {return (name);}
};
```

Comment: try a `std::vector<Apple>` member

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you don't know how to declare an array, how to use it, what its semantics are, and the various ways it will behave different than what you'd expect (especially when you pass it along as a paramenter), you should learn that first before dealing with classes. Also, as the previous comment mentioned, you're better off using an std::vector instead of an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this, this creates array of 50 apples right away when Basket instance is created. If you don't want that you can use `std::vector<Apple>`, which is a dynamic array, instead.

First method:

```
class Basket {
    //class attrs; private
    private:
        std::string name;
        // I want Basket objects to have an array of Apple objects
        // How do I do this?
        Apple apples[50];
    public: //class function
        Basket(std::string); //constructor
        std::string get_name() {return (name);}
};
```

Second Method:

```
 class Basket {
    //class attrs; private
    private:
        std::string name;
        // I want Basket objects to have an array of Apple objects
        // How do I do this?
        std::vector<Apple> apples;
    public: //class function
        Basket(std::string); //constructor
        std::string get_name() {return (name);}
};
```

If you are not sure how to use `vector` class, you can check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) out.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly create an array inside the class Basket using

```
Apple fruit[10];
```

to allow for a maximum of 10 apples in the basket.  So, your `Basket` declaration will look like:

```
// define basket
class Basket {
    //class attrs; private
    private:
        std::string name;
        // I want Basket objects to have an array of Apple objects
        // How do I do this?
        Apple fruit [10];
    public: //class function
        Basket(std::string); //constructor
        std::string get_name() {return (name);}
};
```

Another way will be to create a `vector` of `Apple`s.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you must specify the size as you cannot use an array with an undefined size at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "apple.h" // Don't use <> for your own headers.

class Basket {
    private:
        static const int MAX_APPLES = 10;

        std::string name;
        Apple apples[MAX_APPLES];
    public:
        Basket(std::string);
        std::string get_name() {return (name);}
};
```

Alternatively, you could use a container that changes size dynamically such as `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "apple.h"

class Basket {
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<Apple> apples;
    public:
        Basket(std::string);
        std::string get_name() {return (name);}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If Apple class' constructor has no argument, then you can define apple array as member in Basket class. Otherwise you cannot because you have no way to initialize elements of the array.

Comment: This doesn't apply to C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::vector< Apple >, but you need to consider that std::vector might call object's constructors and destructor behind the scenes (for example when you call resize()). This might cause your objects to do something you have not expected (like delete a chunk of memory and leave a broken pointer).

For large objects with complex behavior it might be better to use std::vector< Apple *>, but std::vector< Apple > would be ok if it's just a struct with some data inside.